# Firebase notifications are not working for google play app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

This is really wierd issue I have!!

My app with firebase notifications.

I am testing it between  two phones: xperia e4g(api 19) and xperia z3(api 23)

Notifications work when( notification received on target device)

1. Sent through fb panel: both api19 and api23
2. Sent by phone to debug version of app : both api19 and api23

3.sent by phone  to release version installed manually on device: both api19 and api23

4. Sent by phone to release version installed from google play: only api19

Notifications does not work when:
1. Sent by phony to release version installed from google play: only  api23

Very thanks for help!
The main frustrating thing that- one app code behavior is different on two devices...

Addon: googleplay services checked on z3(API19) and work correctly

Addon : onMessageReceived Service is not react neither back nor fore ground mode of APP:

Addon : Tested same code on API 16 Samsung GT-N7000 - notifications work good.

Addon: proguard rules case tested ( with and without firebase exclusions)

Current status of issue: two way - particular device has some internal gap exactly for my app  (fantastic!) or API 23 has gap exactly for my app (fantastic still).